# How to get Derby database table in Jupyter notebook dataframe and update table using Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, derby

I want to get my Derby database table into Jupyter dataframe and want to write data back to table. I searched but could not find connection string specific for derby.

Say database name is MyDatabase and there is a table employee with Fname, Lname and HireDate fields.

To access sqlite database, connection string could be something like
conn_str = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///MyDatabase.db')
pd.read_sql('employee', conn_str)

How I will do for Derby table and if the database located at C:\MyProjects\MyDatabase.

Thanks.

Comment: You provide little detail on actual errors encounted, but it seems sqlalchemy doesn't currently support Derby per [this github note](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4839).

Comment: You could export the data from your Derby database using the Derby export features, and import it into your sqlite database for use by Jupyter.

Comment: Thank you ako and Bryan. Will do as Bryan suggested.